# How to display flash message without redirection in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

(This question is a continuation of the following thread:

- [In Rails, is it possible to display an alert without calling redirect_to or render?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56736155/in-rails-is-it-possible-to-display-an-alert-without-calling-redirect-to-or-rend)
- Continuing that question here since there were too many comments in the earlier thread
- There were 2 issues stated in that question and one of them was resolved in that thread
- Hence opening this thread to focus on only the other issue which was not resolved in that thread)

I have a form:

```
<%= form_tag generate_report_path(:header => true) do |f| % >
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div style="padding-right:10px">

    <%= select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select(
      [["Select Report Type", 0],
      ["Report1", 1],
      ["Report2", 2],
      ["Report3", 3]]), id: "report_selection") %>


      <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>
```

I have a submit button and a checkbox right next to it:

```
<%= button_tag "Generate Report", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary'%>
<%= label_tag do %>
  <%= check_box_tag "format_reqd", "format_reqd", false %>
  Check for Numeric format 
<% end %>
```

When the user selects the checkbox and clicks on the `Generate Report` button, I would like to display an alert to the user "your report would be emailed to you in a few minutes"

How can I achieve these:

1. A flash message should be displayed
2. Page redirection or rendering should not happen

Please help!

### UPDATE:

1. I added this to my controller (called `report_controller`):

```
    def reportgen

            respond_to do |format|
              format.json { flash.now[:alert] = "Report generation has been initiated. You will receive an email in approximately 4 - 5 minutes with a link to download the report."}
            end

    end
```

2. `\app\views\report\reportgen.js.erb`

```
    $("#flash").html('<%= j render partial: "shared/notice_banner" %>');
```

3. `application.html.erb`

```
  <div id="flash">
    <% if alert.present? %>
      <%= render partial: "shared/notice_banner" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <% if key.to_s == "alert" %>
      <div style= "color: #FF0000" class="text-center <%= flash_class(key) %>">
      <%= value %>
    </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="lead text-center <%= flash_class(key) %>">
      <%= value %>
    </div>
    <% end %>    
  <% end %>



  <%= yield %>
```

4. `app\views\shared\_notice_banner.html.erb`

```
<div data-alert class="alert-box">
  <%= alert %>
  <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
```

5. And this is my code to add the button and checkbox in my form:

```
                  <div id="generate_button" style="display: none; float:left;">
                    <%= button_tag "Generate Report", class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary'%>
                  </div>
                  &nbsp;
                  <div id="report_type_drop" style="display: none;padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px">


                    <%= label_tag do %>
                      <%= check_box_tag "format_reqd", "format_reqd", false %>
                      Check for Numeric format
                    <% end %>
                    </div>
```

With the above code, flash message still does not appear for me!

### UPDATE: (update2)

I tried changing `flash.now[:alert]` to `flash[:alert]` but still the flash message does not appear

```
            respond_to do |format|
              format.json { flash[:alert] = "Report generation has been initiated. You will receive an email in approximately 4 - 5 minutes with a link to download the report."}
            end
```

Comment: If you don't want a page refresh shouldn't it be a remote form?

Comment: @DaveNewton - even `without` remote, the page refresh is not happening right now. Page refresh was happening when I was using `plain HTML button` and `HTML checkbox`. When I replaced them with `button_tag` and `check_box_tag`, the page refresh stopped happening!!

Comment: What browser? What's rendered? IIRC it defaults to a "submit" type.

Comment: I am using Google chrome. No rendering happens when the button is clicked since no calls to a `render` or `redirect_to` are made. But the flash message is not getting displayed either which is the only focus of this thread.

Comment: What's rendered?

Comment: The original form shown in my question is retained as such when the submit button is clicked. No rendering or redirection happens

Comment: What is rendered on the original page? The form. In html.

Comment: The original page has a form with a bunch of input controls like text boxes, labels etc

Comment: Show th ehtml the form renders.

Answer (score 0):

You need put some javascript async actions in order to do that, you have multiple options:

- Submit the form with ajax, then parse the response and show the alert using javascript
- Use  ajax to check if there is a change in the alert in the server every x seconds
- Use web sockets to check in real time if there is a new alert

which one you want to implement depend of your specific needs